# Access denied on MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine

Tags: msmq

I'm trying to get the list of available queues on the remote machine. The machine is a Win2003R2 in Workgroup mode, and the client machine that runs the code is a Windows 8 machine both using the same Workgroup name. I get an exception when running the following code:

```
var messages = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("Win2003SRV");
```

And the error message is:

```
base {System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException}: {"Access to Message Queuing system is denied."}
Message: "Access to Message Queuing system is denied."
MessageQueueErrorCode: AccessDenied
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with permissions on Windows 2003 but couldn't find  much. The code works fine with another Win Server 2008 (but in workgroup mode) and works with local MSMQ as well. According to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.getprivatequeuesbymachine.aspx), this function is supported on Workgroup mode, so what's the catch?

**SOLVED:**

My issue turned out to be that I didn't have MSMQ installed on my Client machine! The help on the link pointed me to the right direction, so all I had to do was to install MSMQ on client machine as well. If you look at the implementation of GetPrivateQueuesByMachine, the native call can throw a DllNotFoundException and it is that exception that translates into that specific message, so it should give you a hint on what is wrong

Comment: Are you a Local Admin on the 2003R2 machine?

Comment: yes, I've tried local and domain admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Breakwell who is/was a msmq MVP has a few posts which may help. The problem seems to be caused because the GetPrivateQueuesByMachine() method uses RPC under the hood to communicate between queue managers on different machines.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx

Comment: @Hadi Could you explain exactly how that article you linked to helped, please? I'm stuck with a similar issue. Cheers.

Comment: @NeilBarnwell My issue turned out to be that I didn't have MSMQ installed on my Client machine! The help on the link pointed me to the right direction, so all I had to do was to install MSMQ on client machine as well. If you look at the implementation of GetPrivateQueuesByMachine, the native call can throw a DllNotFoundException and it is that exception that translates into that specific message, so it should give you a hint on what is wrong.